# ASP.NET Video Converter Website How to manage user uploaded videos?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a web app for that can convert user uploaded video to different format using ffmpeg. This is my first project idea with using ASP.NET. I would like to ask an advice on how should I manage user uploaded videos to optimize disk consumption.

Comment: That is the actual question? How to most efficiently compress video? How to call ffmpeg from a webserver? And is this a just for fun-project, or do you intend it to be practical to use?

Comment: If the project goes well I would deploy it to an Amazon Lightsail server with a 4GB memory and 80GB ssd for startup

Comment: 60Gb storage is a tiny amount of storage when talking video. A single video file could easily be much larger than that. There is a reason most video companies has their own data centers. Videos are large, and transcoding is CPU heavy, I would recommend doing some economical calculations before doing anything else.

Comment: For startup I would limit the upload limit to 200MB, If the network traffic is somehow increasing then I will try to upgrade.

Comment: That does still not make the question any more clear, SO is for actual programming questions, not a "I have a vague business idea, how do I implement it?" questions.